# Windows-8 scrollviewer doesn't scroll until all content is loaded

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have some content that loads into a XAML scrollviewer in Windows 8. The content takes up to 10 seconds to load on a Surface. But during that time the user can neither tap on an object in the ScrollViewer that has already loaded nor can they scroll the ScrollViewer until all the content has loaded. I've looked through all the IsHitTestVisible that I can find and I even added one to the ScrollViewer, but this still hasn't helped.

Has anyone else run into this issue? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can at least let your user know it's busy loading with a Busy Indicator for starters. Second I would ask, is enough loaded for it to scroll in the first place? If the Height doesn't exceed the Viewport, it would be expected not to.

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying that before. It's horizontally oriented and at the time when we are trying to scroll there is enough content in the ScrollViewer that we should be able to scroll.

We do also present the user with a busy indicator (a Progress Ring to be specific)

Comment: Well since Win8 is based a lot in SL I would assume it's kind of the same where a Busy Indicator (since that's what you're already running) will hijack the UI thread on the object its running over during its duration, so that would account for your HitTestVisibility getting ignored.

Comment: So try taking out the busy indicator and see if that works?... good idea. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try settings these properties on the scroll viewer:-

`<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomMode="Disabled" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Height="400">
    <StackPanel Width="1200" Height="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
        <Border Background="Blue" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Border Background="LimeGreen" Width="400" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>`